# TextField Input via speech(Speech To Text)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm building an iOS app using Swift and Xcode 6. I want to implement speech to text functionality in my app.

I googled and found some links but those are not helpful and some are in Objective c like openEars.

I have two or three textfields where user will enter his/her name,age and location. And there is also a mike button for speech entry in textfield.
Like in image below.
[image]

Could someone help me how i can implement this functionality using Swift.

Help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I googled and found some links but those are not helpful" – specifically? "and some are in Objective c" – and what's wrong with that? It's entirely possible to integrate Objective-C code with Swift code.

Comment: You want to implement openEars library in your swift project?

Comment: So i tried to use openEars in another project that is also not working correctly as my requirement.That i know that we can use Swift with Objective c

Comment: is there any simple and straight tutorial to that can help me to implement this functionality.

Comment: Here is a link to complete tutorial for google speech to text iOS integration. [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ambrose12silveira/google-speech-to-text-stt-api-integration-and-training-model-with-ios-swift-part-i-46519bd41c75)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement openEars this way in your swift project:

first of all add the framework which you downloaded from [here](http://www.politepix.com/openears/).

**Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import <OpenEars/OELanguageModelGenerator.h>
#import <OpenEars/OEAcousticModel.h>
#import <OpenEars/OEPocketsphinxController.h>
#import <OpenEars/OEEventsObserver.h>
#import <OpenEars/OELogging.h>
#import <OpenEars/OEFliteController.h>
#import <Slt/Slt.h>
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SpeechToText
//
//  Created by Anil on 08/07/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Variya Soft Solutions. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

var lmPath: String!
var dicPath: String!
var words: Array<String> = []
var currentWord: String!

var kLevelUpdatesPerSecond = 18

class ViewController: UIViewController, OEEventsObserverDelegate {

    var openEarsEventsObserver = OEEventsObserver()
    var startupFailedDueToLackOfPermissions = Bool()

    var buttonFlashing = false

    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var heardTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadOpenEars()
    }

    @IBAction func record(sender: AnyObject) {

        if !buttonFlashing {
            startFlashingbutton()
            startListening()
        } else {
            stopFlashingbutton()
            stopListening()
        }
    }

    func startFlashingbutton() {

        buttonFlashing = true
        recordButton.alpha = 1

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5 , delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

            self.recordButton.alpha = 0.1

            }, completion: {Bool in
        })
    }

    func stopFlashingbutton() {

        buttonFlashing = false

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {

            self.recordButton.alpha = 1

            }, completion: {Bool in
        })
    }
    //OpenEars methods begin

    func loadOpenEars() {

        self.openEarsEventsObserver = OEEventsObserver()
        self.openEarsEventsObserver.delegate = self

        var lmGenerator: OELanguageModelGenerator = OELanguageModelGenerator()

        addWords()
        var name = "LanguageModelFileStarSaver"
        lmGenerator.generateLanguageModelFromArray(words, withFilesNamed: name, forAcousticModelAtPath: OEAcousticModel.pathToModel("AcousticModelEnglish"))

        lmPath = lmGenerator.pathToSuccessfullyGeneratedLanguageModelWithRequestedName(name)
        dicPath = lmGenerator.pathToSuccessfullyGeneratedDictionaryWithRequestedName(name)
    }


    func pocketsphinxDidStartListening() {
        println("Pocketsphinx is now listening.")
        statusTextView.text = "Pocketsphinx is now listening."
    }

    func pocketsphinxDidDetectSpeech() {
        println("Pocketsphinx has detected speech.")
        statusTextView.text = "Pocketsphinx has detected speech."
    }

    func pocketsphinxDidDetectFinishedSpeech() {
        println("Pocketsphinx has detected a period of silence, concluding an utterance.")
        statusTextView.text = "Pocketsphinx has detected a period of silence, concluding an utterance."
    }

    func pocketsphinxDidStopListening() {
        println("Pocketsphinx has stopped listening.")
        statusTextView.text = "Pocketsphinx has stopped listening."
    }

    func pocketsphinxDidSuspendRecognition() {
        println("Pocketsphinx has suspended recognition.")
        statusTextView.text = "Pocketsphinx has suspended recognition."
    }

    func pocketsphinxDidResumeRecognition() {
        println("Pocketsphinx has resumed recognition.")
        statusTextView.text = "Pocketsphinx has resumed recognition."
    }

    func pocketsphinxDidChangeLanguageModelToFile(newLanguageModelPathAsString: String, newDictionaryPathAsString: String) {
        println("Pocketsphinx is now using the following language model: \(newLanguageModelPathAsString) and the following dictionary: \(newDictionaryPathAsString)")
    }

    func pocketSphinxContinuousSetupDidFailWithReason(reasonForFailure: String) {
        println("Listening setup wasn't successful and returned the failure reason: \(reasonForFailure)")
        statusTextView.text = "Listening setup wasn't successful and returned the failure reason: \(reasonForFailure)"
    }

    func pocketSphinxContinuousTeardownDidFailWithReason(reasonForFailure: String) {
        println("Listening teardown wasn't successful and returned the failure reason: \(reasonForFailure)")
        statusTextView.text = "Listening teardown wasn't successful and returned the failure reason: \(reasonForFailure)"
    }

    func testRecognitionCompleted() {
        println("A test file that was submitted for recognition is now complete.")
        statusTextView.text = "A test file that was submitted for recognition is now complete."
    }

    func startListening() {
        OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
        OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().startListeningWithLanguageModelAtPath(lmPath, dictionaryAtPath: dicPath, acousticModelAtPath: OEAcousticModel.pathToModel("AcousticModelEnglish"), languageModelIsJSGF: false)
    }

    func stopListening() {
        OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().stopListening()
    }

    func addWords() {
        //add any thing here that you want to be recognized. Must be in capital letters
        words.append("SUNDAY")
        words.append("MONDAY")
        words.append("TUESDAY")
        words.append("WEDNESDAY")
        words.append("THURSDAY")
        words.append("FRIDAY")
        words.append("SATURDAY")

        words.append("JANUARY")
        words.append("FEBRUARY")
        words.append("MARCH")
        words.append("APRIL")
        words.append("MAY")
        words.append("JUNE")
        words.append("JULY")
        words.append("AUGUST")
        words.append("SEPTEMBER")
        words.append("OCTOBER")
        words.append("NOVEMBER")
        words.append("DECEMBER")
    }

    func getNewWord() {
        var randomWord = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(words.count)))
        currentWord = words[randomWord]
    }

    func pocketsphinxFailedNoMicPermissions() {

        NSLog("Local callback: The user has never set mic permissions or denied permission to this app's mic, so listening will not start.")
        self.startupFailedDueToLackOfPermissions = true
        if OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().isListening {
            var error = OEPocketsphinxController.sharedInstance().stopListening() // Stop listening if we are listening.
            if(error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error while stopping listening in micPermissionCheckCompleted: %@", error);
            }
        }
    }

    func pocketsphinxDidReceiveHypothesis(hypothesis: String!, recognitionScore: String!, utteranceID: String!) {

        heardTextView.text = "Heard: \(hypothesis)"
    }
}
```

In this code I add one button. By pressing that button you can speak and that lib will recognise your word.

And remember one thing that with OpenEars you can recognise only add word into array and you can not recognise other words.

And you can test [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/OpenEars-with-Swift-) sample project.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks  @Dharmesh Kheni for the answer.By implement this not fulfil my requirement.I want user speak anything like his name and that enter into the textfield.Is that possible with OpenEars.

Comment: No it is not possible with that library. you can read it's document  and you mention here openEars so I added answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! @Dharmesh Kheni.But i want that i mentioned above. If you know how is it possible in iOS.It will be very grateful and your help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry don't have any other idea.